# JOIN two dataframes on common column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a dataframe df:

```
id   name   count
1    a       10
2    b       20
3    c       30
4    d       40
5    e       50
```

Here I have another dataframe df2:

```
id1  price   rating
 1     100     1.0
 2     200     2.0
 3     300     3.0
 5     500     5.0
```

I want to join these two dataframes on column id and id1. Here is an example of df3:

```
id   name   count   price   rating
1    a       10      100      1.0
2    b       20      200      2.0
3    c       30      300      3.0
4    d       40      Nan      Nan
5    e       50      500      5.0
```

Should I use `df.merge` or `pd.concat`?

Comment: @piRSquared Sir, both answers are absolutely correct :) Can't pick both,
just one question, suppose i am dealing with two dataframes each of around 4 million rows. i want the fastest way, in between `join,merge and map` Which one should be the most optimized way

Comment: Both are essentially the same under the hood.  And I don' t care which you pick.  @jezrael and I are always on SO.  We'll get our rep one way or another.  I'm more interested in making sure those 15 rep don't go to waste.  Pick his because he was a few micro seconds faster than me on this one ;-)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='id', right_on='id1', how='left').drop('id1', axis=1))
   id name  count  price  rating
0   1    a     10  100.0     1.0
1   2    b     20  200.0     2.0
2   3    c     30  300.0     3.0
3   4    d     40    NaN     NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0     5.0
```

Another solution is simple rename column:

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'id1':'id'}), on='id',  how='left'))
   id name  count  price  rating
0   1    a     10  100.0     1.0
1   2    b     20  200.0     2.0
2   3    c     30  300.0     3.0
3   4    d     40    NaN     NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0     5.0
```

If need only column `price` the simpliest is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['price'] = df1.id.map(df2.set_index('id1')['price'])
print (df1)
   id name  count  price
0   1    a     10  100.0
1   2    b     20  200.0
2   3    c     30  300.0
3   4    d     40    NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0
```

Another 2 solutions:

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='id', right_on='id1', how='left')
         .drop(['id1', 'rating'], axis=1))
   id name  count  price
0   1    a     10  100.0
1   2    b     20  200.0
2   3    c     30  300.0
3   4    d     40    NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0
```

---

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2[['id1','price']], left_on='id', right_on='id1', how='left')
         .drop('id1', axis=1))
   id name  count  price
0   1    a     10  100.0
1   2    b     20  200.0
2   3    c     30  300.0
3   4    d     40    NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0
```

Comment: keeping this answer, if from df2 i have to select only 1 column 'price' then?

Comment: I dont understand, can you explain more?

Comment: final table has `id name  count  id1  price  rating`
but i want only `price` from df2 not `rating`, then?

Comment: the 2 ways that you suggested both are correct,right?

Comment: Yes, all solutions are correct. If need add more column, nicer and better is `join` (not necessary delete column, left join by default), but if need add only one column  `map` is faster.

Comment: for two huge dataframe(say each df has around 4 million rows, should i use merge or map?
which one would take less time to complete

Comment: do you need add one or 2 columns?

Comment: just a question, my requirements may change, sometimes one column sometimes 2 columns. which one would be best in both the cases

Comment: hmmm, I try test it, but `join` or `merge` is more universal.

Comment: I try test if `join` or `merge` is faster.

Comment: Just make sure you set your keys as index on your dataframes before joining.  Something I had trouble with for a moment.

Answer (score 11):

`join` utilizes the index to merge on unless we specify a column to use instead.  However, we can only specify a column instead of the index for the `'left'` dataframe.

***Strategy:***

- `set_index` on `df2` to be `id1`
- use `join` with `df` as the left dataframe and `id` as the `on` parameter.  Note that I could have `set_index('id')` on `df` to avoid having to use the `on` parameter.  However, this allowed me leave the column in the dataframe rather than having to reset_index later.

---

```
df.join(df2.set_index('id1'), on='id')

   id name  count  price  rating
0   1    a     10  100.0     1.0
1   2    b     20  200.0     2.0
2   3    c     30  300.0     3.0
3   4    d     40    NaN     NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0     5.0
```

---

If you only want `price` from `df2`

```
df.join(df2.set_index('id1')[['price']], on='id')


   id name  count  price
0   1    a     10  100.0
1   2    b     20  200.0
2   3    c     30  300.0
3   4    d     40    NaN
4   5    e     50  500.0
```

Comment: keeping this answer, if from df2 i have to select only 1 column 'price' then?