# How to iterate through two data frames in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Data frames `df1`( having columns C1,C2,etc) and `df2`(having columns S1,S2,etc)
I want to iterate through each column of both the Data Frames.
Currently I am doing the following thing:

```
df3=pd.Dataframe([])
for index1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['C1']==row2['S1']:
            #perform Some Operations on each row like:
            df3 = df3.append(pd.DataFrame({'A': row2['S1'], 'B': row2['S2'],'C':functionCall(row1['c3'], row2['S3'])}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

This works ok but it takes too much time.
 I wanted to know, Is there a more efficient way of iterating through two Data Frames?

Comment: Have you tried MERGE? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463119/join-two-dataframes-on-common-column-in-python

Comment: Can I call a function to make column 'C' in `merge`?

Comment: What is function `functionCall` ?

Comment: the function call is fuzzy search `fuzz.token_set_ratio(row1['C3'], row2['S3'])`

Comment: I want to find `fuz.token_set_ratio()` for each row of first dataframe with that of 2nd data frame if the `if ` condition is satisfied.Please help..i am new to python coding

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) first, then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function and last filter columns by subset - `[[]]`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='C1', right_on='S1')
df3['C'] = df3.apply(lambda x: functionCall(x['C3'], x['S3']), axis=1)
df3 = df3[['S1', 'S2', 'C']].rename(columns={'S1': 'A','S2': 'B'})
```

Comment: @Momel - Thank you.